# How can I put a camera with a standard tripod point on my head?

Tags: camera

I've got a video camera with a standard screw-in tripod point. I would like to put that camera on my head to make a video while cycling.

Are there any helmet mounts or similar I can purchase designed to work with a standard tripod mount?

(GoPro have lots, but I understand those use a different mount than the standard tripod point. If thats right, those won't be suitable.)

Comment: Two words:  Duct Tape  :)

Comment: At least use gaff tape, so you can easily peel it off later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what size your cameras is, but a quick search at [B&H turned up this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/755950-REG/Midland_XTA104_XTA_104_Vented_Helmet_Camera.html):

[image: Midland XTA-104 Vented Helmet Camera Mount]

Midland XTA-104 Vented Helmet Camera Mount

Comment: It's a Sony Webbie. This item looks ideal. If only they would deliver to England. :)